# Trying to save the values of a channel in Golang

Tags: go, goroutine

Everything seems to work fine for me, I'm producing the matrix just like I want. If I print <-M1, I get exactly what I want. But how do I save that for use somewhere? Very new to this, any help greatly appreciated.

That doesn't look like an incompatible assign haha.

Thanks,

Follow up:

```
go func(abc *[SIZE / 2][SIZE / 2]int) {

        go add(A11, A22, A1)
        go add(B11, B22, A2)
        first, second := <-A1, <-A2
        go multiply2(*first, *second, M1)
        abc = <-M1
        fmt.Print(*abc)

    }(abc)

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    fmt.Print(*abc)
```

When I print *abc inside of the go function, it returns the array fine. Outside, it's a nil pointer.

Comment: You have not provided all the types in your screenshot. Please instead provide a _complete_ example as a text of a program.

Comment: Also, avoid images when copy-paste-able text will do (see [ask]). In the case of Go language examples, a clickable [Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/) is helpful as well.

Comment: Cheers, fellas. I really am very new to this.

Comment: Please provide it as text.

Comment: I've replaced the images with text. I really have no clue how I could provide more though, those other functions are pretty involved. But if I print <- M1 instead of trying to save it I get a &[[229017 205278 219741 215326 212325 175418 20636 reference to an array I guess?

Comment: Given both `M1` and `abc` are channels: you cannot assign a value from `M1` to `abc`. `abc` should be of `*[SIZE / 2][SIZE / 2]int` type to be able to do that.

Comment: `var abc *[SIZE / 2][SIZE / 2]int
 
 abc = <- M1`

Comment: You're a gentleman. Thanks for your patience and your help.

Comment: Hi zerksm, I added a follow up to the main if you happen by here again. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: In Go all function arguments are passed by value, including pointers. In other words, the anonymous function receives a copy of a pointer. Making this copy point somewhere else has no effect on the caller's copy of the pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Golang channels are designed for communicating between goroutines. If you want to store a list of values it could make sense to store the values in a slice.

```golang
vs := []int{}

vs = append(vs, *abc)
```